# google map spiderfier cluster

Tags: javascript

Question about spiderfier cluster, I managed to make it work with markerClusterer but is there a way to auto spiderfied it when you zoomin so it won't show just 1 marker when map is zoomed?

Say if you hit maxZoom level of 11 then it should automatically spiderfied the markers.

Here's my spiderfier options:

```
 var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {keepSpiderfied : true, markersWontMove : false, circleSpiralSwitchover: 5});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

(function(){

```
var gm = google.maps;

var config = {
    el: 'map',
    lat: 37.4419,
    lon: -122.1419,
    zoom: 15,
    minZoom: 15,
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var spiderConfig = {
    keepSpiderfied: true,
    event: 'mouseover'
};

// A list of Markers with the same location
var data = [
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'location 1'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'location 2'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 3'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 4'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 5'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 6'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 7'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 8'},
    {lat: 37.4419, lon: -122.1419, title: 'Marker same location 9'}
];


function initialize() {

    var map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById(config.el), {
        zoom: config.zoom,
        center: new gm.LatLng(config.lat, config.lon),
        mapTypeId: config.type
    });


    var markerSpiderfier = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, spiderConfig);

    var markers = [];


    for (var x in data) {

        var loc = new gm.LatLng(data[x].lat, data[x].lon);

        var marker = new gm.Marker({
            position: loc,
            title: data[x].title,
            map: map
        });

        marker.desc = data[x].title;

        markers.push(marker); // Saving Markers

        markerSpiderfier.addMarker(marker);  // Adds the Marker to OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier
    }


    var iw = new gm.InfoWindow();

    markerSpiderfier.addListener('click', function(marker, e) {
        iw.setContent(marker.title);
        iw.open(map, marker);
    });

    markerSpiderfier.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
        iw.close();
    });


    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

    markerCluster.setMaxZoom(config.minZoom);

}

gm.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

})();